# Target the 2nd instance of a CSS Class

Tags: css, css-selectors

Due to the solution I am using, I only have limited CSS classes. I would like to know if there is a way I can target the 2nd class, when there are 2 classes of the same name.

I have 2 instances of media-link contained withing a DIV called item. I need to basically add additional styles to the 2nd instance of the class. However this is where the difficulty comes in... I can not add any additional code, or classes to the code! I know, not ideal but its down to the solution being used, not personal choice.

Example code:

```html
<a href="#" class="media-link" style="display: block">
  <img src="images/ph-a.png" alt="" />
</a>
<a href="#" class="media-link">
  <img src="images/auth-2-100px.png" alt="" />
  <p class="author">Author: John Smith</p>
</a>
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions, or solutions.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There are two pseudo-selectors that accomplish what you're looking for.

```css
.media-link:nth-child(2) {
  // here style 
}
```

or

```css
.media-link:nth-of-type(2){
  // here style
}
```

Comment: looking good Rohit, i will test it out and see how it goes ;)

Comment: While this solution works for the specific scenario listed above, it should be noted that nth-of-child and nth-of-type do NOT select the nth instance of the element with the provided class. Rather, they select the element with the provided class IF it is the nth-of-type or nth-child in relation to the parent element. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/0Lsan8vb/

Comment: Oh my god is that an important caveat.

Answer (score 6):

you can use `nth-child pseudo classes` for your requirement....

```
.media-link:nth-child(2) {
color:red;
}
```